# Match columns with multiple criteria using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a MATCH of columns using multiple criteria, as in the example below:

```
A1: Part   B1:  Code   C1:  Price   D1:  Find Part  E1:  Find Code
A2: x      B2:  11     C2:  5.00    D2:  y          E2:  12
A3: x      B3:  12     C3:  6.00
A4: y      B4:  11     C4:  7.00
A5: y      B5:  12     C5:  8.00
```

Where D2 and E2 are criterias. If D2 and E2 match with columns A and B respectively, I should get the result from corresponding column C. (In this example: 8.00)

For this example I tried the following Formulas on Excel:

```
=LOOKUP(D2&E2;A2:A5&B2:B5;C2:C5)
{=INDEX($C$2:$C$5;MATCH(D2&E2;$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5;0))}
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5=D2);--(B2:B5=E2);INDEX(C2:C5;0;0))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A5=D2);--(B2:B5=E2);C2:C5)
```

All of them give me the RIGHT result in Excel and OOCalc. But when using POI, I get errorcode 15 from the first one. Exception *Unexpected eval type* from the second, and Exception *Invalid arg type for SUMPRODUCT* from the third and last formulas.

Does anyone know how to match columns with multiple criteria by using a Formula which can be parsed by Apache POI?

Note: With Apache POI I'm successfully matching columns with one single criteria. So, I guess the error is not in my code, but maybe the format of those Formulas above aren't supported by POI.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/formula.html says array formulas are not yet supported (your 1st, 3rd and 4th formulas are just aliases for array formulas, i'm affraid)

if you can insert a new column with formulas like `=A2&B2` and match this new column, that would solve your problem..

Comment: Well, that's true, but I wasn't allowed to change the .xls file from the customer. Also, I couldn't create the formula virtually in my Workbook due to heavy specifications. At the end, I had to convince them to add this column. =(